# l-value specifies const object when using std::make_pair

Tags: c++, stl

```
struct MapInserter
{
private:
    int count;

public:
    explicit MapInserter()
        : count(0)
    {
    }

    std::pair<int, std::string> operator()(std::string& value)
    {
        return std::make_pair(count++, value);
    }
};

vector<std::string> words = { "one", "two", "three","four","five" };
std::map<int, std::string> map;
MapInserter inserter;
transform(words.begin(), words.end(), map.begin(), inserter);

for (auto it = map.begin(), end = map.end(); it != end; ++it)
    cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << endl;

return 0;
```

that's the code. VS returns a compile error regarding `l-value specifies const object`.

Clicking the error moves you to the following code in a file named utility

```
template<class _Other1,
    class _Other2>
    _Myt& operator=(pair<_Other1, _Other2>&& _Right)
    {   // assign from moved compatible pair
    first = _STD forward<_Other1>(_Right.first);
    second = _STD forward<_Other2>(_Right.second);
    return (*this);
    }
```

at first, i've had the `operator()` take `const std::string&` so I removed the const, because it's obviously talking about the make_pair function. But it still hasn't gone away. Can anyone point me to what this error is about?

Comment: Why are you taking `value` by lvalue reference? Just take by value and move, or take by reference to `const`. I just had a quick look at the code but I guess that may solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not certain how to express it formally, but I suspect it's getting hung up on `count++`, and would do better if you moved the incrementation out of the call to std::make_pair().

Comment: `std::pair<int, std::string> operator()(std::string value) { return std::make_pair(count++, value); }` still giving the error

Comment: @Logicrat it's not it

Comment: The problem is most likely that `transform` tries to assign into the elements of the map, but the keys of a map are `const` (to prevent from messing with the internal ordering of the container).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `std::transform()` will try to *assign* to existing elements of the target container. Keys of a map are constant and cannot be assigned to, which is why you're getting a compiler error. But even if they were, you'd get undefined behavior at run-time here, because the target container is empty, and `std::transform()` would expect it to contain as many elements as the input range.

You should use [`std::inserter()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) to create an inserter iterator, like so:

```
vector<std::string> words = { "one", "two", "three","four","five" };
std::map<int, std::string> map;
MapInserter inserter;
transform(words.begin(), words.end(), std::inserter(map, map.begin()), inserter);
//                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here is a [*live example*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d7b739502d8158f).

Moreover, taking the `value` string by mutable lvalue reference in the call operator of your `MapInserter` is not a good idea: you don't want the argument to be modified, so you should either take it by `const&` or - my advice - take it by value and then move it into the returned pair, like so:

```
std::pair<int, std::string> operator()(std::string value)
{
    return {count++, std::move(value)};
}
```

Since `std::pair`'s constructor is not `explicit`, you do not even need the call to `std::make_pair()` in this case.

Comment: Yup. worked like charm. only had to remove the `<int, std::string>` from `make_pair` @thab suggested and returned to it to a `const&`

Comment: I know about the const ref stuff. From my c++ training i'm used to only take by-val if i absolutely have to.

Comment: @GioraGuttsait: In fact, as I wrote in the last edit to the answer, you don't even need `make_pair()`. You can just use brace list initialization.

Comment: @GioraGuttsait: Concerning pass-by-value, that's my preferred choice when it's a *value* that I need to pass, unless I have performance problems. It clearly communicates that a value is being copied, and no sharing is necessary between caller and callee. [This article](http://josephmansfield.uk/articles/need-value-pass-by-value.html) explains it quite well.